# how to predict an image using saved model

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

```
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy.misc
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
# dimensions of our images
img_width, img_height = 313, 220
# load the model we saved
model = load_model('model.h5')
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy','mse'])
test_image= image.load_img('/Images/1.jpg',target_size = (img_width, img_height))
#x= scipy.misc.imread('/Images/1.jpg').shape
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
print test_image
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height*3)
result = model.predict(test_image)
print result
```

When I ran the above code I get this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (36,) but got array with shape (660,)

Comment: `model.predict` accepts mini batches

Comment: Try to use model.summary to see which dimensions are used for your layers.

Comment: input_dim=36 but still don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: @Jennifer95 - if an answer helped you, please accept it by clicking on the green tick, so we can mark the question as resolved. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 2):

Having problems with dimensions is very common. As others have mentioned, the method `predict` expects to get a batch of images. You should run `model.summary()` to see what the expected dimensions of the input are. The batch size itself might have been designed to be flexible during training, by specifying `None` in the first dimension on the model `input_shape` parameter.

Without knowing more of the dimensions, I cannot say exactly where your problems lies. You could include that information by editing your question.

---

It will likely help to have a look at the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict) for predict function of the model objects.

There is an argument: `batch_size`, which defaults to **32** if not fixed by the model itself, which you can see from the `model.summary()`. If you set this equal to 1, perhaps you will get a prediction.

Below is a modified version of your code that I would expect to return a prediction.

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

# dimensions of our images    -----   are these then grayscale (black and white)?
img_width, img_height = 313, 220

# load the model we saved
model = load_model('model.h5')

# Get test image ready
test_image = image.load_img('/Images/1.jpg', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)

test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height*3)    # Ambiguity!
# Should this instead be: test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height, 3) ??

result = model.predict(test_image, batch_size=1)
print result
```

**Note**: there is ambiguity in the dimensions where I highlight it. A colour image will have three dimensions: (height, width, 3). Black and white will have only two dimensions: (height, width).

Comment: Can you explain further on batch size as 1? Why will someone do that?

Comment: @Aditya - The question was how to get a prediction for a single image. If we wanted to predict on 10 images, we could make `batch_size = 10`. When using the `predict` function, we are not updating the weights of the model; no backpropagation is performed. That means the `batch_size` argument really just tells the model how many images we are pushing through the network.

Comment: So an equivalent would be to make multiple copies of the same IMG array and feed it?

Comment: Yep - that would give then an identical prediction, given identical inputs, as random behaviour is not present at test time. It is a bit of a hack though, which is why I opted to answer with the more computationally efficient method.